# Need to execute code before Ignite cache ExpiryPolicy

Tags: caching, ignite, cache-expiration

I am using Ignite cache with ModifiedExpiryPolicy and need to execute a line of code before event execution. Any help?

```
IgniteCache<String, Object> expiresCache = cache.withExpiryPolicy(new ModifiedExpiryPolicy(new Duration(Time.MINUTES, timeInMins)));

public class ClassName {
public IgnitePredicate<CacheEvent> functionName() {
    return new IgnitePredicate<CacheEvent>() {  
        @Override
        public boolean apply(CacheEvent evt) {
            //code to be executed after event.
            return true;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Before or after the event? Your wording and the comments disagree?

Comment: @StephenDarlington 
Before.
The after is just executed in the block above , but need to know how to do something just before that

Comment: where can I add such line?

Comment: Could you give more details please? What are trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I need to access the object for database update  (adding log) just before it's removed from cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to [use events](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/events) to listen for expiry events.

```
Ignite ignite = Ignition.ignite();

// Local listener that listenes to local events.
IgnitePredicate<CacheEvent> locLsnr = evt -> {
  System.out.println("Received expiry event [evt=" + evt.name() + ", key=" + evt.key());

  return true; // Continue listening.
};

// Subscribe to specified cache events occuring on local node.
ignite.events().localListen(locLsnr, EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_EXPIRED);
```

Note that this is just a *local* (node) listener, you'll need a remote listener to find expiry events on remote nodes. You'll also need to configure `includeEventTypes` in your configuration file (events are disabled by default for performance reasons.